# Ratio test to solve series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am given the following:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{{(n+3)!} (4^n)}{{5n}^{n+2}} 
$$

I am using ratio test to solve this, but the division part in the ratio test is confusing me. This is shown below:

$$
\lim_{n=\infty} \frac{{(n+3+1)!} (4^{n+1})}{{(5n+1)}^{n+2+1}} . \frac{{(5n)}^{n+2}} {{(n+3)!} (4^{n})}
$$

Comment: You should actually have $$\lim_{n=\infty} \frac{{(n+3+1)!} (4^{n+1})}{{(5n+1)}^{n+2+1}} . \frac{{(5n)}^{n+2}}{{(n+3)!} (4^{n})} $$

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Yup, sorry. Typing mistake

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the left fraction's denominator should be $$(5(n+1))^{n+2+1}=(5n+5)^{n+3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=\frac{(n+3)!4^n}{5n^{n+2}}$.

To use the ratio test, we want to calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n+1}/a_n$:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+4)!4^{n+1}}{5(n+1)^{n+3}}}{\frac{(n+3)!4^n}{5n^{n+2}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+4)!4^{n+1}5n^{n+2}}{(n+3)!4^n5(n+1)^{n+3}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4n+16}{n+1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4n+16}{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}\\
&= \frac{4}{e}>1
\end{align*}
so by the ratio test, this series diverges.

Comment: But the answer states that it diverges

Comment: Then I assume my interpretation of your denominator was incorrect. I will edit my post as soon as I can.

Comment: the post has been edited using a different interpretation to correctly show that the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Stirling formula:
$$
\log\frac{{(n+3)!} (4^n)}{{5n}^{n+2}} = \log (n+3)! + n\log 4 - (n+2)\log n - \log 5
\\=\ (n+3)\log (n+3) - (n+3) + n\log 4 - (n+2)\log n+ O(\log n)\\
=  n(\log 4-1) + O(\log n)\to\infty
$$so the series is divergent.